# Is it possible to download bpy version 3.6.2

Tags: python, pip, blender, bpy

I use bpy package for blender automation. I am using scripting in blender for development/testing and standalone python script for production. I use `bpy.ops.render.render()` to render image and I have found that in blender it works (there is bpy version 3.6.2) but in my script it does not (bpy version 3.6.0). So I was searching and found out that there was this fix in bpy version 3.6.2:

> Regression: Cycles render crash using F12 render after running script that uses bpy.ops.render. [#109718](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/109718)

Which is probably the cause of this problem. Therefore I need to download this version (3.6.2) but it is not in pip and I cannot seem to find it anywhere else.

**Is it possible to download this version from somewhere?**

(Also I am using python 3.10.11 and in blender python 3.10.12 is used although I don't think it has anything to do with my problem.)